# Проверить, находится ли точка в окружности

Tags: python, оптимизация

Всем привет!

У меня такой вопрос: имеется несколько областей на экране, записанных в массив. Дана точка (куда кликнул пользователь), нужно определить в какие области кликнул пользователь (точка может быть одновременно в нескольких).

У меня больше вопрос по оптимизации. Ведь я циклом перебираю все области и проверяю по формуле лежит ли точка в ней.

Подскажите, как можно ускорить работу алгоритма или сделать так, чтобы он съедал меньше памяти?

Comment: без вашего когда не понятно что улучшать

Comment: Видимые оптимизации сразу. 1) Оквадратить окружности. Точка, не лежащая в описанном квадрате, не лежит и в окружности, а проверка - только 2 сравнения координат без вычислений; 2) Список связности (пересечения) окружностей. Точка, лежащая в окружности, заведомо не лежит в другой окружности, которая с этой не пересекается. И то, и другое уменьшит количество проверяемых окружностей на попадание. PS. Надеюсь, Вы сравниваете не расстояние до центра с радиусом, а их квадраты?

Comment: *как можно ускорить работу алгоритма, или сделать так, чтобы он схедал меньше памяти?* Определитесь. Это почти наверняка противоречащие друг другу желания.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример пример массив с координатами точек и радиусами, чтобы была понятна структура массива? Как часто вам надо делать такие проверки? Если часто можно ли аккумулировать точки ("куда кликнул пользователь") и проверять их все сразу или частями?

Comment: [55.755831, 37.617673, 15, 1] - вот пример точки [Y, X, R, ID_circle]

Comment: Может каким-то образом можно воспользоваться бинарным поиском?(Отсортировать окружности)? Или может быть хэш-таблицы как-то помогут? Подскажите пожалуйста, может кому-то в голову что-то придет

Comment: @Андрей, [вариант с numpy + scipy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668123/211923) вас не устраивает?

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо большое! Устраивает. Просто уже из интреса ищу самое-самое оптимальное решение:)

Comment: @Андрей, вы не ответили на мой предыдущий вопрос - вам надо искать попадание __одной__ точки или сразу многих/нескольких?

Comment: @MaxU Да, извините. Вот именно что нескольких. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: @Андрей, и что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @MaxU Список id всех областей которым принадлежит точка

Comment: @Андрей, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668421/211923). Если считаете что вам был дан правильный ответ [отметьте его как верный](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Зачем вы удалили метку языка? Теперь из вопроса даже непонятно, что нужен именно Python (ну дам я вам ответ на C или C++, станет ли вам легче?). Вернул метку на место.

Answer (score 3):

вот рабочий пример с использованием Numpy и Scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist

N = 10**5   #  число окружностей (областей)
x = np.random.randint(10, 1910, N)   # случайные X координаты для дисплея с разр. 1920 x 1080 
y = np.random.randint(10, 1070, N)   # случайные Y координаты для дисплея с разр. 1920 x 1080
r = np.random.randint(10, 250, N)    # случайные радиусы в диапазоне: 10 - 250
ids = np.arange(N)

a = np.column_stack((x,y,r, ids))
```

получилась матрица 100.000 x 4 (x, y, radius, circle_id):

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]:
array([[  889,   680,   120,     0],
       [  643,  1056,   160,     1],
       [ 1075,   165,   133,     2],
       ...,
       [  996,   359,   240, 99997],
       [ 1545,   401,   182, 99998],
       [ 1421,   489,   229, 99999]])

In [16]: a.shape
Out[16]: (100000, 4)
```

найдем расстояния от всех центров окружностей до точки с координатами (555, 222) и выберем все окружности в которые эта точка попадает:

```
d = cdist(a[:, :2], [[555, 222]]).ravel()
a[d <= a[:, 2]]

In [17]: a[d <= a[:, 2]]
    ...:
Out[17]:
array([[  735,   254,   232,     3],
       [  682,   298,   231,    18],
       [  542,   360,   246,    38],
       ...,
       [  680,    68,   231, 99769],
       [  641,   128,   175, 99936],
       [  643,   227,   179, 99968]])
```

Число таких окружностей:

```
In [19]: a[d <= a[:, 2]].shape
Out[19]: (3238, 4)
```

Замер скорости для 100.000 окружностей:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: d = cdist(a[:, :2], [[555, 222]]).ravel()
    ...: a[d <= a[:, 2]]
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop
```

Замер скорости для 1.000.000 окружностей:

```
In [21]: %%timeit
    ...: d = cdist(a[:, :2], [[555, 222]]).ravel()
    ...: a[d <= a[:, 2]]
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop

In [22]: a.shape
Out[22]: (1000000, 4)
```

---

**UPDATE:** микрооптимизация - предварительно отфильтруем те окружности в которые наша точка заведомо не попадает (алгоритм такой же как у [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667907/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment968277_667907)):

```
# счиатем расстояния до всех центров окружностей
def f(px, py, a):
    return a[cdist(a[:, :2], [[555, 222]]).ravel() <= a[:, 2]]

# предварительно фильтруем (убираем) те окружности
# для кот. точка лежит за кважратом описывающим окружность
def f2(px, py, a):
    m = a[((a[:, 0] - a[:, 2]) <= px) & (px <= (a[:, 0] + a[:, 2]))]
    return m[cdist(m[:, :2], [[px, py]]).ravel() <= m[:, 2]]
```

**Timing:** для 1.000.000 окружностей:

```
In [57]: px, py = 555, 222

In [58]: a.shape
Out[58]: (1000000, 4)

In [59]: %timeit f(px, py, a)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.7 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit f2(px, py, a)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

> Проверить принадлежат ли точки окружностям

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
```

**Окружности (формат строки: `x`, `y`, `radius`, `circle_id`):**

```
In [114]: a
Out[114]:
array([[1831,  489,   14,    0],
       [ 454, 1058,   36,    1],
       [1761,  621,   64,    2],
       [1042,  901,   86,    3],
       [ 889,  836,  135,    4],
       [ 123,  534,   75,    5],
       [ 213,  585,   79,    6],
       [1619,  761,   84,    7],
       [1265,  263,  110,    8],
       [1191,  295,  128,    9],
       [ 267, 1056,  175,   10],
       [ 947,  172,  108,   11],
       [1665,  666,   17,   12],
       [ 434,  903,  189,   13],
       [1023,  483,  108,   14],
       [1170,  721,  189,   15],
       [1092,   30,  225,   16],
       [  59,  998,   85,   17],
       [1333,  718,   20,   18],
       [ 193,  575,   75,   19]])

In [115]: p
Out[115]:
array([[1530,   27],
       [  70,  690],
       [1800,  123],
       [1313,  380],
       [ 809,  920],
       [1071,  204],
       [1123,  876],
       [ 626,  613],
       [ 842,  980],
       [1366,  651]])
```

**Точки (формат: `x`, `y`):**

```
In [125]: p
Out[125]:
array([[1195,   51],
       [ 771,  555],
       [ 376,  843],
       [  22,  512],
       [1504,  949],
       [  54,  646]])
```

**Функция нахождения областей/окружностей для всех точек:**

```
def get_matching_circles(p, c):
    """
    p - points: 2D array containing X, Y coordinates
    c - circles: 2D array. Row format: X, Y, Radius, Circle_ID 

    Returns: all circle_id's containing at least one point
    """
    return c[(cdist(c[:, :2], p) <= c[:, 2, None]).any(axis=1), 3]
```

**Пример:**

```
In [128]: get_matching_circles(p, a)
Out[128]: array([13, 16])
```

**Пошагово:**

[scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) считает расстояние между каждой парой точек составленных из двух входных массивов. На выходе получаем матрицу расстояний, в которой в первом столбце - расстояния от первой точки до центров всех окружностей, во втором - расстояния от второй точки до центров всех окружностей и т.д.. Т.е. размерность результирующей матрицы: (`число окружностей` x `число точек`):

```
In [129]: cdist(a[:, :2], p)
Out[129]:
array([[  772.2305,  1062.0527,  1497.4448,  1809.1462,   564.3837,  1783.9221],
       [ 1250.252 ,   594.557 ,   228.7116,   696.2327,  1055.6425,   574.2334],
       [  803.2783,   992.1976,  1402.6792,  1742.4127,   416.6929,  1707.1831],
       [  863.6602,   439.4963,   668.5208,  1091.6597,   464.4868,  1020.3769],
       [  842.5325,   304.7704,   513.0478,   925.562 ,   625.2951,   856.344 ],
       [ 1175.7861,   648.3402,   399.362 ,   103.3683,  1442.0076,   131.5485],
       [ 1117.8014,   558.8059,   305.177 ,   204.4749,  1341.334 ,   170.2997],
       [  826.968 ,   872.6626,  1245.7018,  1616.2951,   220.3838,  1569.2196],
       [  223.2577,   573.8467,  1061.4711,  1267.6948,   726.4413,  1270.122 ],
       [  244.0328,   493.9636,   982.1044,  1188.9701,   725.0414,  1189.9454],
       [ 1367.9214,   710.6455,   239.2697,   596.6247,  1241.6191,   462.0271],
       [  275.9438,   421.5033,   881.0687,   985.5075,   956.022 ,  1011.002 ],
       [  774.0317,   900.8646,  1301.0957,  1650.2015,   325.5918,  1611.1241],
       [ 1142.3769,   484.4306,    83.4506,   568.0009,  1070.9883,   458.7472],
       [  464.9817,   262.084 ,   740.4114,  1001.42  ,   669.7141,   982.6139],
       [  670.4663,   432.1539,   803.3181,  1166.8697,   404.4008,  1118.5173],
       [  105.119 ,   615.3584,  1083.3397,  1173.5519,  1007.1271,  1207.0211],
       [ 1478.954 ,   838.566 ,   352.8654,   487.4064,  1445.8306,   352.0355],
       [  681.1263,   585.1607,   965.129 ,  1327.0859,   287.4056,  1281.025 ],
       [ 1130.7431,   578.3459,   324.5196,   182.2361,  1363.3037,   156.0833]])
```

Сравниваем расстояния от точек до центров окружностей с радиусами окружностей:

```
In [130]: cdist(a[:, :2], p) <= a[:, 2, None]
Out[130]:
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько много окружностей? При наличии кода было бы понятней, попробуйте сделать генератор с условием вместо цикла по массиву:

```
my_big_list = [1, 2, ... n]
result = [i for i in my_big_list if i == 777]
```

Если я не ошибаюсь это будет экономить оперативку, выгружая поочередно эл-т из списка, когда цикл выгрузит весь список.

То, что касается ускорения работы - [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html)

Он работает гараздо быстрее.